# A and B are two matrices such that $(A+B)^3=A^3+3A^2B+3AB^2+B^3$ then $ AB=BA$

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be two invertible matrices in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$such that $(A+B)^3=A^3+3A^2B+3AB^2+B^3$ then prove or disprove that $ AB=BA$

My working:

$$(A+B)^3=A^3+3A^2B+3AB^2+B^3$$
$$\implies BA^2+B^2A+ABA+BAB =2A^2B+2AB^2$$

Now what should I do?

Comment: I saw the counterexample $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix}-2 & 0 \\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.  This gives $AB = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$, $BA= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -2 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$, $(A+B)^3 = A^3+3A^2B + 3AB^2 + B^3 = \begin{bmatrix}
-8 & 3 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$, but why is it deleted?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy I got it thanks

Comment: I got one result $AB=BA\iff B=xA+yI_2$ where $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Counter-example :

$$
A=
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2  & 0 \\
   &   \\
0 & 3 \\    
\end{array}\right),
B=
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1  & 0 \\
   &   \\
1 & -10 \\    
\end{array}\right).
$$

Comment: It should be more enlightening that you explain to the OP how you obtained the counterexample. :)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I tried an example with $A$ diagonal